# Problemas con un trigger en ORACLE

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, plsql

ando aprendiendo ORACLE y me cree un trigger que después de cada inserción en la tabla *Comisión* se agregue en la columna *Pago_Com* data desde la tabla *UEA* que a su vez está relacionada con la tabla *Guia_Transito* y cuando intento insertar en la tabla *Comision* me salta este mensaje:

> single-row subquery returns more than one row

Este es mi trigger:

```
create or replace trigger ocex_comi_total
after insert or update of id_gt on ocex_comi
begin
    update ocex_comi cm set
    cm.PAGO_COM= (select uea.total from OCEX_GT_PER GTP
                join OCEX_PER P ON GTP.ID=P.ID_PER
                join OCEX_GUIA_TRANSITO GT ON GTP.ID_GT=GT.COD_GT
                join OCEX_UEA UEA ON GT.DEST_ENTREG=UEA.N_MINA)
where cm.ID_GT = (select gtp.id_gt from OCEX_GT_PER gtp);
end;
```

Alguna orientación para que me deje insertar y cargue los datos? Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

en principio uno de los dos select te debe estar devolviendo mas de un una fila.

No conozco la estructura de la BD, asi q te diria q es imposible contestarte, pero puedo orientarte mas con el segundo select.

Es posible (y es una suposción de mi parte) que talvez el deberia quedar asi el where:

```
where cm.ID_GT = :new.id_gt
```

Es decir q actualice con un valor X la columna PAGO_COM, obtenido a partir del primer select, en el registro de la tabla donde ID_GT sea igual al valor ID_GT del registro insertado/actualizado.

Y adivinando te diria q tu trigger deberia quedar algo mas parecido a esto:

```
update ocex_comi cm set
    cm.PAGO_COM= (select uea.total from OCEX_GT_PER GTP
                join OCEX_PER P ON GTP.ID=P.ID_PER
                join OCEX_GUIA_TRANSITO GT ON GTP.ID_GT=GT.COD_GT
                join OCEX_UEA UEA ON GT.DEST_ENTREG=UEA.N_MINA
                where GTP.ID_GT = :new.id_gt)
where cm.ID_GT = :new.id_gt;
```

Espero haber sido claro y que mi respuesta al menos te oriente un poco.
Saludos.

Comment: Si, por decir  en el     select uea.total from OCEX_GT_PER GTP
                join OCEX_PER P ON GTP.ID=P.ID_PER
                join OCEX_GUIA_TRANSITO GT ON GTP.ID_GT=GT.COD_GT
                join OCEX_UEA UEA ON GT.DEST_ENTREG=UEA.N_MINA
... Añado un where cod_gt=90818 y si me devuelve el total. Pero en el trigger no especifico el valor del cod_gt será por eso?

Comment: exacto. Si al momento de ejecutarse el trigger, el select devuelve mas de un resultado, el update te va a dar error porque no sabe cual de todos los valores debe guardar en "cm.PAGO_COM". Y asumo q en el segundo select tenes el mismo problema.

Comment: @waltercerrudo te recomiendo darte una vuelta por este enlace https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer para que trates de mejorar tu respuesta ya que tiene muy poco contenido y parece mas un comentario, se bienvenido y agradecemos todos tu interes por ayudar

Comment: @waltercerrudo si de hecho que sí, entonces cual sería el cambio que debería hacerse en los select para poder determinar el valor que debe guardar?

Comment: @waltercerrudo lo edité como me sugeriste y pues el error cambio table OCEX.OCEX_COMI is mutating, trigger/function may not see it. Ahora si cambio el AFTER por un BEFORE me permite dejar insertar pero me sale campo NULL en el pago_com